# PDO FetchAll Array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I know that $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); returns the result in an array to the variable, but how would you go around extracting the information from the array? Say the variable holds 3000 entries.

Thank you

Comment: it gives you a two-dimensional array... either loop through the array or access a particular record via it's zero-based index.

Comment: @orangepill What did you mean by two dimensional? Assming the variable is $hello = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); I can't just do $hello[0][blah]?

Comment: I mean that it is an array of arrays. you would access the field name id in the first record by `$hello[0]["id"];`

Comment: or each of the row's id elements in turn via `foreach($hello as $row){ echo $row["id"]; }`

Answer (score 1):

If you mean extract information from what `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` returns, you need to set it to a variable.

```
$returned_results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($returned_results as $key=>$result) {
     echo "<pre>"; var_dump($result); echo "</pre>";
}
```

This will dump every result, which will show you how to directly access the array hierarchy.

Which will end up being something like:

```
$returned_results[2]['somefield'];
```