# Trouble using foreach in PHP to access results of SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a simple table called `people` with three fields.  Eventually I'd like to use the results of a SELECT query to populate the default values of a form, but for now I'm just trying to echo the results of the query.  I've tried lots of things and now I'm getting an 'array to string conversion' error on line 11 (the `echo`).  Here's what I'm trying:

```
<?php
 include 'connect_db.php';
 $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM people");
 $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ':' . $value . '<br>';
 }  
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're iterating rows, where `$key` is just index number and `$value` is an array representing database row. You can't echo array like that.

Comment: Nest another foreach on $value.

Comment: use print_r($value) in side foreach loop. then you can understand how that array .

Comment: OK, that clarifies things a little.  I get: `Array ( [first_name] => Bob [last_name] => Smith [name_id] => 2 ) 1` .  (An aside--what is the `1` at the end?)  But I'm still not clear on what to do about it.  Do I need to specifically refer to each column by name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO FetchAll Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295164/pdo-fetchall-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO prepared SELECT statement isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18647416/2943403)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing to an associative array value from PDO::FETCH_ASSOC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22620594/2943403)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO fetch array of arrays. Outer has numeric index. Inner has associative index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27967238/2943403)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning a query result to an associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43831188/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get back an associative array for each row. The keys will be the column names.

```
 include 'connect_db.php';
 $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM people");
 $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 foreach ($results as $row) {
  echo $row['some_column_name'] . '<br>';
 }
```

Or

```
 include 'connect_db.php';
 $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM people");
 $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 foreach ($results as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value){
       echo $key . ', ' . $value . '<br>';
    }
 }
```

Comment: Does that mean I need to repeat `echo $row['some_column_name'] . '<br>';` for each column?

Comment: just updated answer. But yes, you need to access each column either explicitly or by looping again over the individual row.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is clear, you cannot display an array, which means you can try to use json_encode($value)

or

you can use print_r($value) not echo

Comment: That's the proximate problem, but the actual problem is that the wrong thing is being iterated over.

Comment: yes, and with that we can see what happen with the $value, soo he can use the correct one, or can you show me the other way?